# GRASS 7.6 Add-on install issue

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I've been trying to install add-ons wihtout success.  I keep getting an error message:

> ****IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060]**** Une tentative de
>   connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu
>   convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion
>   établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu
>   (Mon Oct 28 22:16:44 2019) La commande s'est terminée (21 sec)

(Google Translation)

> ****IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060]**** A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond properly beyond a certain time, or an established connection failed because the login host did not respond (Mon Oct 28 22:16:44 2019) The order has ended (21 sec)

I've seen posts pertaining to this issue but haven't been able to fix it through editing the g.exetension.py file.  Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Hi, is it possible that you have a firewall there which requires a proxy to the set?